# time derivative of a function f(x,y,z,t)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can anyone help me understand howcome:

$$df(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)/dt = \partial(f)/dt + \nabla(f) \cdot \partial(x,y,z)/dt$$
where $\partial(x,y,z)/dt$ represents of course the velocity
what i cant understand really well is the $\partial(f)/dt$.
(sorry for the lack of notation, i dont know how to use these tools yet)

what i thought was $(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)=m(t)$
therefore:
$$df(m(t))/dt = \nabla(f) \cdot \partial(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)=
\partial(f)/dx \cdot \partial(x)/dt +..+ \partial(f)/dz \cdot \partial(z)/dt+ \partial(f)/dt \cdot \partial(t)/dt$$

Is that correct?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's It is just a special case for the chain rule with

$$f=f(t,x(t),y(t),...)$$

indeed in this special case, since $x,y,...$ are function of one variable $t$, we have

$$\frac{d f}{d t} =\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \cdot \frac{\partial t}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}+...=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}+  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{dy}{dt}+...$$

This special case as [**total derivative**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) of $f$ with respect to $t$.